# how to use jQuery.post() in joomla

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I created a component for joomla.in this component I want to show a form to the user and get name of the user and send her name to the server via ajax.i try this code for get data from user in default.php file.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');?>
<div id="results"></div>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
  <input type="button" class="button" id="savename" value="Save Name">
    <?php
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
   ?>
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#savename").click(function(){
   var name = jQuery('#name').val();
   jQuery.post("/components/contactf/ajax.php?name="+name , function(response){
               jQuery('#results').html(jQuery(response).fadeIn('slow'));
   });
  });
});
</script>
```

my component name in  "contactf".jquery.post() can not call ajax.php file.I think problem is 
`"/components/contactf/ajax.php?name="+name` .I do not know how to set argument for `jQuery.post()` correctly.ِDo I need to use `JPATH_BASE` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like ,

```
jQuery("#savename").click(function(){
      var name= jQuery("#name").val();
      var data = 'name='+name;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&task=yourcontroller.your_function",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
           alert(data);

        }
    });
  });
```

Here `yourcontroller` is the related controller file and `your_function` is the function inside controller.

Inside your controller function

```
function your_function(){

  $name = JRequest::getVar('name');
  //Do what ever you want

  exit;
 }
```

If you are using Joomla 3. x Requesting parameters as follows.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$name   = $jinput->get('name');
```

More about [receiving post data](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Hope it make sense..

Comment: `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` = Joomla 3 so you shouldn't use `JRequest` ;)

Comment: ajax alert return source of html page !

Comment: make sure in your controller function you added exit;

Comment: @Erfanpj - I made a mistake with the comment. You should still use `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` to import jQuery. Instead of `JRequest`, Jobin Jose has provided you with the Joomla 3.x alternative in his answer, at the bottom

Comment: Hi . Is there any simple sample for calling ajax in joomla 3 and 3.x ?!
I really confuse ... :(

Answer (score 0):

create a view with help of MVC, e.g.

*ajax/view.json.php*

in your component

and then send the post data to this view

```
jQuery.post( "index.php?option=com_contactf&view=ajax?name="+name+"&tmpl=component" , function(response){
                   jQuery('#results').html(jQuery(response).fadeIn('slow'));
```

Then in your view.json.php run all the php code and return an outcome in json format.

Jan